# Preg_match on multiline text

Tags: php, preg-match

With Casimir et Hippolyte's help, I've been trying to parse some text like that shown in the example below (note: my original question oversimplified the sample text - because I assumed I'd easily be able to adapt any solution provided to the actual text. However after banging fingers on keys and heads on walls, I'm still none the wiser).

Here's what I have so far... I've tried escaping data (addslashes), but thought I'd post $subject in its raw(er) form...

```
<?php

$subject = "
YdqkÂ‚_,¦#¦#À%¦#¦#¦#¦#¦#èeèe2%Ž¦#¦#¦#Cf¦#¦#¦#¦#qk¦#¦#¦#¦#¦#¦#¦#¦#¦#Ð     ð:SOME COMPANY<br />
WITH A LONG NAME<br />
The Big Barn, 23 London Lane, Cheltenham, Glos. GL1 1GL<br />
Tel. 022234 567890 Fax. 02234 345678 Email.  <a href= mailto:info@some.co.uk </a>info@some.co.uk<br />
Company: Another Company (AKA) – 22 London Lane, Cheltenham, GL1 2GL<br />
FAO: Mr D. Mistify/ A. Clarity/ Jo Bloggs<br />
PROJECT OMAHA   <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    CONTRACT No.    14  DATE    10/6/13 <br />
    No. QUESTION    ANSWER  <br />
    <br />
973 <br />
Hi, it's me again:<br />
I'm very, very confused. Why do regular expressions seem such a dark art?<br />
Surely it can't be as hard as I manage to make it seem?<br />
Please advise<br />
Thank you.  <br />
Date Required – <br />
17/6/13 <br />
    <br />
Signed for and on behalf of Some Company with a Long Name Limited<br />
Me Again – Senior Moment<br />
________________________________________________________<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
QUESTION / ANSWER SHEET<br />
Some Company with a Long Name<br />
<br />
Question and Answer System<br />
AA414<br />
’“¸¹ÉÊËÌÔ...descends into gibberish...
";

$pattern = '~
    Project\hNo\.\h\d++\hDATE\h
    (?<date>\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2})
    \s++No\.\hQUESTION\hANSWER\s++
    (?<No>\d++)\s++

    # all characters but D or D not followed by "ate Required"
    (?<desc>(?>[^D]++|D(?!ate\hRequired))+)

    \D++
    (?<date_required>\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2})
~x';

preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

print_r($matches);

?>
```

I'd like to extract the following:

- the published date (10/6/2013) (dd/mm/yyyy)
- the question number (973)
- the description
- the date required (17/6/2013) (dd/mm/yyyy)

Comment: And so-far you've tried ...? (& protip: php regex has an [`m` modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php))

Comment: the solutions are all simple ... once you've arrived at them. here's a hint: to `preg_match` on on multiline text, use `/m`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to avoid the issue of new lines by not using the dot (`$subject` is your string):

```
$pattern = '~
    Project\hNo\.\h\d++\hDATE\h
    (?<date>\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2})
    \s++No\.\hQUESTION\hANSWER\s++
    (?<No>\d++)\s++

    # all characters but D or D not followed by "ate Required"
    (?<desc>(?>[^D]++|D(?!ate\hRequired))+)

    \D++
    (?<date_required>\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2})
~x';

preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

print_r($matches);
```

Note that i use [possessive quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html%E2%80%8E) and [atomic groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html%E2%80%8E) to avoid as possible backtracks

#### EDIT:

According to your new example string, i give you a new type of pattern (in a kind of lex style) that is more readable and more editable:

```
$pattern = <<<LOD
~
 # Raw types
 (?(DEFINE)(?<uint>  \d++                      ))
 (?(DEFINE)(?<date>  \d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2} ))

 # Custom types
 (?(DEFINE)(?<void>  (?>\s++|<br\b[^>]*+>)*           ))
 (?(DEFINE)(?<desc>  (?>[^D]++|D(?!ate\h++Required))+ ))

 # Anchors
 (?(DEFINE)(?<A_prj_date>      PROJECT(?>[^D]++|D(?!ATE\b))+DATE\h*+    ))
 (?(DEFINE)(?<A_prj_number>    \g<void>No\.\h++QUESTION\h++ANSWER\b\D++ ))
 (?(DEFINE)(?<A_prj_desc>      \g<void>                                 ))
 (?(DEFINE)(?<A_prj_date_req>  Date\h++Required\D++                     ))

 # Pattern
 \g<A_prj_date>     (?<prj_date>      \g<date> )
 \g<A_prj_number>   (?<prj_number>    \g<uint> )
 \g<A_prj_desc>     (?<prj_desc>      \g<desc> )
 \g<A_prj_date_req> (?<prj_date_req>  \g<date> )    

~xi
LOD;
```

It begins with the definition of each component you need.

1. Raw types: subpatterns that you can see everywhere
2. Custom types: subpatterns specific to your project
3. Anchors: subpatterns that describe the transition between required fields

After, you have the pattern itself composed with these elements.

You obtain something highly editable, since you can adapt all subpatterns to you needs, add new subpatterns and compose new subpatterns with others.

Example, you can try to replace the *A_prj_number* subpattern with `\D++` that seems to be good enough for your example string:

```
(?(DEFINE)(?<A_prj_number>\D++))
```

Another advantage of this syntax, you can easily debug your pattern commenting one by one the elements (in the pattern section) from last to first until you obtain a match:

```
# Pattern
 \g<A_prj_date>     (?<prj_date>      \g<date> )
 \g<A_prj_number>   (?<prj_number>    \g<uint> )
 # \g<A_prj_desc>     (?<prj_desc>      \g<desc> )
 # \g<A_prj_date_req> (?<prj_date_req>  \g<date> )
```

note: if you have only one project by string use *preg_match* instead of *preg_match_all*.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I think I may have oversimplified the problem but I'll have another bash at it with what I've learnt here...

Comment: Thanks, that looks very, very promising. I can't test it until tomorrow, but the fact that it's more readable (for me) should help immensely both for this problem and similar problems in the future. Thanks again.